# ipset v4.5: Unknown set type

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, ipset

I compiled `ipset` on CentOS5 32bit machine and i am getting weird errors

My kernel:

```
[root@localhost ipset-4.5]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.18-400.1.1.el5 #1 SMP Thu Dec 18 00:58:32 EST 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

ipset version:

```
[root@localhost ipset-4.5]# ipset -V
ipset v4.5, protocol version 4.
Kernel module protocol version 4.
```

Try to create hash.

```
[root@localhost ipset-4.5]# ipset --create test macipmap --network 192.168.10.0/24
ipset v4.5: Unknown set type
```

I check `man` example and trying here but no luck

```
[root@localhost ipset-4.5]# ipset -N test iphash --probes 2
ipset v4.5: Unknown set type
```

iptables rule:

```
[root@localhost ipset-4.5]# iptables -A INPUT -m set --set badips src -j DROP
iptables v1.3.5: Couldn't load match `set':/lib/iptables/libipt_set.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

iptables version:

```
[root@localhost ipset-4.5]# iptables -V
iptables v1.3.5

[root@localhost ipset-4.5]# rpm -qa | grep iptables
iptables-1.3.5-9.2.el5_8
```

Answer (score 0):

**Found solution myself:**

need to load `ip_set_iphash.ko` kernel module.

```
# insmod /lib/modules/2.6.18-400.1.1.el5/extra/ip_set_iphash.ko
```

iptables v1.3.5 has missing library `libipt_set.so` to fix it do following:

```
# wget http://ftp.neu.edu.cn/mirrors/CentALT/5/i386/iptables-1.3.5-5.6.1.el5.i386.rpm
# rpm2cpio iptables-1.3.5-5.6.1.el5.i386.rpm | cpio -idmv
# cp lib/iptables/libipt_set.so /lib/iptables/libipt_set.so
```